# PyGTK Horizontal List

Tags: user-interface, pygtk

I have a presentation program, and I have a vertical list with slides. I was wanting to put a horizontal list for re-ordering, and easy movement between slides.

It would look something like this, and might even have a horizontal scrollbar:

```
+------+------+------+------+-+
|  S1  |  S2  |  S3  |  S4  | |
 <===========================>   Scrollbar
+-----------------------------+
```

Does PyGTK have support for a horizontal list that I am overlooking, or do I need to implement it using a table? Or maybe a better interface would be just to have another vertical column, but I kind of like the idea of a horizontal list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [CellView](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkcellview.html) may be what I'm looking for. I'll have to play with it to make sure, but it sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an [HBox](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkhbox.html)? Put it on a [Viewport](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkviewport.html) and a [ScrolledWindow](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkscrolledwindow.html) and you will have scrolling support.

Comment: I thought about HBox, but I was wanting something that looked like a list/table. I would have to use buttons or something in an HBox.